# ElectronJS - Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

Electron outputs an error - cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Tried removed electron globally and locally and reinstalling but it still gives the same error

Terminal Cmd used to run electron - npm start

Index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

const { App, BrowserWindow } = electron

let mainWindow

App.on('ready', function() {
 console.log('App is now ready!')

 //Main Window
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({})

 mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'Index.html'),
  protocol: 'file',
  slashes: true
 }))
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read electron's document https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app carefully. It must be `app` not `App`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! i thought after destructing it, i can assign any name to the variable.